# Sqlite on Azure: The server was not found or was not accessible

Tags: sqlite, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using SQLite in an Asp.Net MVC 5 project which is working fine.

I uploaded the application to Microsoft Azure and I got the following error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

In Azure I added the following connection string:

```
Data Source=D:\home\site\wwwroot\Data\MyDatabase.sqlite;Password=pass
```

Since there is no SqlLite database option I selected Custom:
[image]

I checked using Azure Kudu and the file is in the right path ...

However, when I run the application I keep getting the error.

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

My Entity Framework class is the following:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(Configuration))]
public class Context : DbContext, IDbContext {

  public Context() {
    Configuration.With(x => {        
      x.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
      x.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
      x.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
      x.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
    });
  }

  public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
  public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder) {
  }

}

public class Configuration : DbConfiguration {
  public Configuration() {
    SetDatabaseInitializer<Context>(null);    
    SetProviderServices(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, SqlProviderServices.Instance);
  }
}
```

And I have the following on Global.asax:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Data");

builder.RegisterType<Context>().As<IDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
```

The connection string in Web.Config is:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Context" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;Password=pass" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: And how exactly is your website hosted? using a VM with IIS or web app or something else? This error is sql server specific by the way so are there any leftover configurations maybe? Or your code is calling sql server. Can you post the code where you use this connection string?

Comment: It is hosting as a Web App ...

Comment: @PeterBons I just updated my code to better explain what I have. This is working fine in my development machine. But it does not work in Azure.

Comment: I think you need a slash. I haven't checked, but I would think that your SetData statement would set the data directory to something like 'wwwrootdata' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of defining a ConnectionString in Azure I need to define an Application Setting in Azure for DataDirectory where the value is the directory in Azure where the database is ...

The absolute path of the database location in Azure can be found using Kudu's Debug Console.

Following my example the DataDirectory application settings would have:

```
Key: DataDirectory
Value: D:\home\site\wwwroot\Data
```